# Make base_field of ArrayField unique for a table in Django

Tags: python, django

## Goal

The following should raise a `ValidationError`

```
>>> m1 = MyModel(names=['name1'])
>>> m2 = MyModel(names=['name1', 'name2'])
>>> m1.save()
>>> m2.save()
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ...
```

In plain English, if an element in a model's `ArrayField` matches an element in the database table a `ValidationError` should be raised

## Failed Solutions

[ArrayField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) don't mention the `unique` keyword so I tried doing this a couple ways (these are minimal code examples).

Adding `unique=True` to the `base_field` didn't seem to the anything at all after running `makemigrations` and `migrate`

```
# models.py
... 
class MyModel(models.Model)
    title = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True),
    )
```

```
...
# shell_plus from Django-extensions
>>> m1 = MyModel(names=['name1'])
>>> m2 = MyModel(names=['name1'])
>>> m1.save()
>>> m2.save()
# no errors raised
```

I tried adding `unique=True` to only the `ArrayField`. Django raises an error if an *array* is exactly the same.

```
# models.py
...
class MyModel(models.Model)
    title = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=255),
        unique=True,
    )
```

```
# shell_plus from Django-extensions
>>> m1 = MyModel(names=['name1'])
>>> m2 = MyModel(names=['name1'])
>>> m1.save()
>>> m2.save()
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ...
>>> m3 = MyModel(names=['name1', 'name2'])
>>> m3.save()
# no error raised
```

The above makes sense when I think it about. I then tried to add `unique=True` to both the `base_field` and to the `ArrayField` but the behavior didn't change. I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    title = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True),
        unique=True,
    )
```

```
# shell_plus from Django-extensions
>>> m1 = MyModel(names=['name1'])
>>> m2 = MyModel(names=['name1'])
>>> m1.save()
>>> m2.save()
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ...
>>> m3 = MyModel(names=['name1', 'name2'])
>>> m3.save()
# no error raised
```

## TL;DR

Can I make the following raise an error with `unique=True` or do I need to write my own validators?

```
>>> m1 = MyModel(names=['name1'])
>>> m2 = MyModel(names=['name1', 'name2'])
>>> m1.save()
>>> m2.save()
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minimal example of what I ended up doing

```
# models.py
...
UNIQUE_ARRAY_FIELDS = ('name',)

class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def prevent_duplicates_in_array_fields(self, model, array_field):
        def duplicate_check(_lookup_params):
            fields = self.model._meta.get_fields()
            for unique_field in UNIQUE_ARRAY_FIELDS:
                unique_field_index = [getattr(field, 'name', '') for field in fields]
                try:
                    # if model doesn't have the unique field, then proceed to the next loop iteration
                    unique_field_index = unique_field_index.index(unique_field)
                except ValueError:
                    continue
            all_items_in_db = [item for sublist in self.values_list(fields[unique_field_index].name).exclude(**_lookup_params) for item in sublist]
            all_items_in_db = [item for sublist in all_items_in_db for item in sublist]
            if not set(array_field).isdisjoint(all_items_in_db):
                raise ValidationError('{} contains items already in the database'.format(array_field))
        if model.id:
            lookup_params = {'id': model.id}
        else:   
            lookup_params = {}
        duplicate_check(lookup_params)

...

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=255),
        default=list
    )
    objects = MyManager()
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        MyModel.objects.prevent_duplicates_in_array_fields(self, self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```